# android recyclerview only shows first item only marshmallow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

Android RecyclerView only shows first item on marshmallow, but it works fine on lollipop & shows all the items.
Please note that I am using the recyclerview inside scrollview so that I did

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

and still working fine with lollipop but it doesn't with marshmallow.

Comment: Show your code. Also instead of scrollview use `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem :) (y)

Answer (score 2):

In your **Item Layout** set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the **Root element**.

This would solve the issue.

Comment: it's Item Layout set android:layout_height="wrap_content" at the Root element, but still the problem exists.